# send password field with get method and ajax is still unsafe?

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, get

if i send password field with `get` method and ajax is still unsafe?

if i send password field with `html form` ,password can see in URL.

```
<form method='get'>
     <input type"password" name="pass" />
     <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

URL can see as `example.com/?pass=inputpass`

but if i send with ajax(get method) password can't see anywhere.

so this is correct way

or why should don't use ajax+get to send password?

Comment: I assume we're talking http and not https here?

Comment: why would you do that, instead of `POST`?

Comment: i use `POST`, but i want know `POST` vs `GET` is not different for send password(with ajax)?

Comment: There is not real difference, but `POST` support more characters to be sent, and that can be really important when it comes to length of data when is encrypted. as mention in the answer, make sure all traffic is encrypted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is still insecure. To get more security, hash it before you send it then also hash it server side plus salting. Also make sure to use https/tls. However it is not the ajax or "get" way itself that is insecure.

You can use ajax and get, just make sure the traffic is encrypted and that the password is hashed

Someone can intercept the traffic and capture the password.

As bobince says, the request URL can be cached/intercepted. Therefore you should use post instead so that the parameter(password hash) gets encrypted.

Comment: This is not a good advice as someone who has access to the server’s access log files could use the hash in a replay attack as the hash would work just like the password.

Comment: I think you missunderstood or you are wrong? You have to send the password at some point, then its better to have it hashed on the wire. Then you can give some kind of token with TTL(often a cookie) that is retransmitted with each request for authentication. However, the cookie can also be replayed as can the password/hashed password. Its therefore important for the provider to provide SSL and an XSS safe application, and for the user to keep their system safe(malicious plug-ins etc).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you send the password or hash of the password for authentication. Because in the latter case the hash would act as password. Only if the hash would only be valid once a replay attack would be mitigated.

Comment: Yes, thats a risk you cannot avoid even if you are using none Ajax with post?

Comment: Well, with POST it wouldn't show up in the access logs.

Comment: I get your point about the access logs but the fact is that the question is about sending the password. Then if you are sending the password it is better to send a hashed version of it.

Comment: It’s only better with regard to that an eavesdropper won’t get hold of the actual password in clear text. But as the hash would act as key to pass authentication, a replayed request would be authentic as long as there is no replay mitigation in place. That means, it’s more important to have HTTPS and POST as request method than to just replace the actual password by a hash.

Comment: yes I wrote "Also make sure to use https/tls" and "As bobince says, the request URL can be cached/intercepted. Therefore you should use post instead so that the parameter(password hash) gets encrypted."

Answer (score 7):

> why should don't use ajax+get to send password?

If you don't see the URL in the address bar, that means the URL isn't subject to leakage through browser history or referrers, so that's certainly a bit better than the disastrous plain form+GET case.

But the URL might still be logged and potentially leaked by anything else that touches the request (proxies, caches, the web server itself, government agency data mining...). In general it is a convention that URLs are non-sensitive and fair game for logging and analysis, so you shouldn't put really sensitive data like credentials, credit card numbers etc in them. These are better off going by POST.

If you really do *have to* put an access token in a URL, there are mitigations you can use to make that less dangerous. For example instead of passing a password that is good indefinitely, one could write a server-issued time-limited or single-use token, so that if someone came across an old URL in logs at some point in the future then that URL would no longer be accepted.

But for a normal local-server AJAX request there is no obvious reason you would need to do that.